# Intercept a click on the built-in myLocation-Button of a GoogleMap

Tags: android, geolocation, google-maps-markers, android-maps-v2

Is there any way that I can intercept/catch a click on the myLocation-Button on a GoogleMap (API v2)? The reason I need this is this:

I calculate distances to my map markers. The default reference location for these calculations is the users location. But as soon as the user searches for an address, this search result is used as reference for the distance calculations.
I want to intercept a click on the myLocation button to tell my app that it should use the users location again for calculating the distances.

I could implement my own "goToMyLocation"-button anywhere in my layout, but I'd prefer the Android-styled button of GoogleMap to achieve a consistent Android experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new API of Google Play Services 3.2 there is a `onMyLocationButtonClick()` Method that is called whenever the myLocation-Button is clicked. From the [Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener.html):

> true if the listener has consumed the event (i.e., the default behavior should not occur), false otherwise (i.e., the default behavior should occur). The default behavior is for the camera move such that it is centered on the user location.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to intercept click events for this button. You need to implement your own one

Comment: well, this is not the answer I was hoping for, but it's still an answer. Do you have any references for your statement? Did you try it yourself or is there any official description from Google? I searched their sites, but haven't found anything on this topic...